# Grails/GORM/HQL: Eliminate inner query in FROM part

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

I have a table "Table" similar to this one:

```
id     user_id      owner_id      due_date
------+------------+-------------+--------------------------
1     | 1          | 1           | 2011-07-26 12:28:50
2     | 1          | 1           | 2011-07-26 15:32:11
3     | 1          | 1           | 2011-07-27 08:11:58
4     | 2          | 1           | 2011-07-26 15:19:44
5     | 2          | 1           | 2011-07-23 12:00:50
```

As you can see, a user identified by FK `user_id` can have multiple entries with different `due_date`.

I would like to fetch all most recent `Table` entities grouped by user_id.

In plain MySQL, it could look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM TABLE
      WHERE owner_id = xxx
      ORDER BY due_date DESC
  ) AS sorted
GROUP BY user_id
```

I would first select with ORDER BY, then apply a GROUP BY (all in one SELECT doesn't work, unfortunately. see e.g. here http://www.cafewebmaster.com/mysql-order-sort-group).

Now I would like to implement this as HQL (with Grails). The problem is that HQL does not support inner SELECT's in the FROM part, so the following approach won't work:

```
def findMostRecentPerUser( Owner owner ) {
    def result = Table.executeQuery("""
                from Table as t1
                where t1.id in (
                    select sorted.id from (select * from Table as t2 where t2.owner_id = ${owner.id} order by t2.due_date desc) as sorted group by sorted.user_id
            )
        """)
    return result
}
```

Another way would be a Criteria but I've no idea how to implement it that way.

Could someone point me into the right direction? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to return a collection of dates?

Comment: I think i'm confused.  Why do you need a sub query? Is it just to order by the date?

Comment: I would like to select entire rows, i.e. full `Table` entities for further usage within Grails. I have clarified this in the original question. The subquery is required since a simple `GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY due_date` does not lead to the correct result, see here for a similar problem description: http://www.cafewebmaster.com/mysql-order-sort-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way should work. Improvements appreciated.

```
def findMostRecentPerUser( Owner owner ) {
    // Inner query sorts maximum due_date per user
    // Outer query fetches all Table entries with this due_date
    def result = Table.executeQuery("""
            from Table as t1
            where t1.due_date in (
                select max(t2.due_date) from Table as t2 where t2.owner = :owner group by t2.user
            )
        """,
        [ owner: owner ] )
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just leave MySql out of it and just get the results back and use a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort.  This way you can garentee sort will be the same regardless of how a database implements it.

```
List<Table> results = query();
Collections.sort(results, YourCustomComparator.getInstance());
```

Doing this will also decrease the load on your database because it turns into a simple query without an order by.

See the Collections doc [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

Comment: Thanks for your replies, Michael. Since the result set may become quite big and I don't want to load all records just to sort them, I'd prefer to handle this in the query. Besides, an HQL query should also abstract database implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that what you're intending is possible (I'm not even sure you *should* be able to do it with raw SQL).

You want to use a `Group By` statement which (in my understanding) only has meaning when used in conjunction with aggregate functions, but you're not using an aggregate function.  I assume your goal is to get a data structure looking like this: `[user_id_1: [t1, t5, t2], user_id_2: [t3, t4, t8]...]` (where tX is an instance out of `Table`) is that correct?

If that's the case I think you just need to get the set of instances you care about back and organize them yourself:

```
def findMostRecentPerUser( Owner owner ) {
  def someDate = new Date() - 5 // 5 Days ago
  def result = [:].withDefault{[]}
  Table.withCriteria {
    eq('owner.id', owner.id)
    gt('due_date', someDate)
    order('due_date', 'desc')
  }.each{result[it.user.id] << it}
  return result
}
```

However, as you can see, this only gives you instances that occurred after some date (or, removing the `gt` statement, it gives you all instances, which is probably not what you want).  You could restrict it down to the single most recent instance per user by using `distinct('user.id')`

But if you wanted, say, the 5 most recent instances for each user I think you'd be stuck doing a query for each user (and limiting the result set to 5, of course).  I'm very interested in seeing a solution for this case if someone has one.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, except the fact that I'm only interested in the single most recent row per user. I've already tried applying a distinct but this basically has the problem as the GROUP BY issue above - the following code returns the wrong rows since the distinct seems to be applied first.
def results = Table.withCriteria {
 eq( "owner", owner )
 projections {
  distinct( "user" )
 }
 order( "due_date", "desc" )
}

Comment: Ah, so it would.  Hmm...The only other thing I can think of would involve a refactor: adding a field to User for mostRecentTable then you could join on that property to limit the results in the correct manner (which would be crummy in requiring updating the User object whenever an associated Table object is created--suppose you could do it with another association table which might be better).  I don't have any other ideas on doing it strictly with your query.  Good Luck!